# Correction after sending definitive proof of article to journal

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, proofreading

I have recently replied the copy-editor of a journal with a version of the article's proof, stating that they should proceed to publication after I checked all the comments for this last proof.

However, the next day an error was spotted in the funding acknowledgement provided in this last proof, and I would like to change this. I have already written the journal's production an email saying that this was a mistake, asking if it would be possible to receive another proof with this minor change. Are there any possibilities this can be accepted, and there is still a chance that proceeding to publication can be stopped to check this?

Answer (score 1):

You've already done what you should: contact the journal. My guess is that they will be able to make the change. They may just do it and not send you a second proof. If it's too late then it's too late and probably not significant enough to warrant a correction in the next issue. Perhaps they can fix it in an on line version.